# Sum 5 largest numbers in each row, dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a league table with Column A displaying a list championship entrants.

In the corresponding row are the entrants various race results (points scores). i.e. ColC shows Race 1, ColD Race 2 etc.

I want to sum total, per row (entrant), the 5 largest scores (in Col B)

The following formula works fine entered line by line,

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(LARGE($H5:$AE5,{1,2,3,4,5,6}),0)))
```

However, I want it to be a dynamic array formula that self populates, should new entrants be added.  Something like (though this doesn't work):

```
=arrayformula(If(A2:A<>"",ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(LARGE($H5:$AE5,{1,2,3,4,5,6}),0))),""))
```

I've been trying to use MMULT, and a few other haphazard ideas, unsuccessfully.

Test sheet can be used here;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18tmKdwAcXoDQrQxSDSnzgK6A5Erj22oSXcxwUt_lq4o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am unable to access the sheet - can you check the permissions plz?

Comment: Sorry Tom, please try now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work even with hundreds or thousands of rows. You can find it on the new tab called mk.help

=Arrayformula({"TEST";if(A3:A="",,VLOOKUP(A3:A,query({query(vlookup(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A3:A)*10,1,0)/10+3,{row(A3:A),A3:A,D3:M},mod(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A3:A)*10,1,0),10)*{0,1}+{2,3}),"order by Col1,Col2 desc"),Mod(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A3:A)*10,1,0),10)},"select Col1,Sum(Col2) where Col3<5 group by Col1"),2,0))})

Comment: Thanks works great!  Now I just need to figure out how that works ;)

Comment: You're welcome! I'll try to demo a bit more extensively on your sample sheet. It uses a sort of retabulation method I came up with a while back to first get everyone's scores into just two columns.

Comment: Interesting!  I'm struggling a bit to get it to work on the real sheet, which is a little different to the test sheet.  As well, I have been told they want six scores....but I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: hey Nick, i'm jumping back on the test sheet if you're around to chat.

Comment: well, i missed you but I updated the demo tab to finish out my explanation.  hope it helps!

Comment: Hey Matt, just wanted to say thanks for this.  I obviously missed adding a comment.  The explanation was really useful, and I was able to get my sheet working perfect in the end.  Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

In B3 put this formula:

```
=arrayformula(query({transpose(split(textjoin(",",false,{left("",row(A3:A5))} & join(",",column(D3:M3)-column(D3))),",",true,false)),sort(split(transpose(split(textjoin("*",false,{row(B3:B5) & "^" & D3:M5}),"*",true,false)),"^",true,false),1,true,2,false)},"Select sum(Col3) where Col1<=4 group by Col2 label sum(Col3) ''"))
```

but you must modify this for more than row number 5

Comment: Thanks!  I've marked the previous response, by Matt, as the answer, as it works with as many rows as required, without edits.  Otherwise, your solutions works great.